# Replace HTML tags with contents using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a below string in javascript.

var maturityDlgPrincipleSelectHtml = "<option value="Renew">Renew</option><option value="Redeem">Redeem</option>";

I want to delete option tags which contain "Redeem" value from the string maturityDlgPrincipleSelectHtml using regex expression. So the expected result would be

maturityDlgPrincipleSelectHtml = "<option value="Renew">Renew</option>"

Comment: `var maturityDlgPrincipleSelectHtml = "<option value="Renew">Renew</option><option value="Redeem">Redeem</option>";` should give you an error... You have to escape the quotes.

Comment: yes, to escape \ character is used. I tried to find "Redeem" value and to replace the entire tags with empty string using RegEx but failed. Please help me to provide Regex expression to replace.

Comment: Okay, then please fix your formatting and update your code to reflect that. As for the RegExp + HTML, obligatory _[don't do it answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2006429)_. Convert your string to an HTML object and work off of that.

Comment: See [this short example](http://jsbin.com/viquzoqisi/edit?js) on how to parse a string of HTML the _right_ way.

Comment: @Sumita Sinha why are you keeping this in a single variable.if you are going to have only these two add them in separate variables.dont include the option with value redeem  if your condition satisfied.dont complicate things by doing Regular expression.use regular expression for appropriate things

Comment: Without regex, if any other way I can achieve to find the "Redeem" value and replace the whole tag with empty string?

Comment: @Sundar: I am getting a string in a single variable with multiple options value. So out of them, I need to find the option tag containing "Redeem" value and remove that option tag from the string. Please suggest any other way?

Comment: @Sumita Sinha /<[a-zA-z\s=]{1,}>Redeem</[a-zA-z\s]{1,}>/ try this regular expression

Comment: @Sundar: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I have the below string

Comment: var str2 = '<option value="Renew">Renew</option><option value="Redeem">Redeem</option><option value="Withdraw">Withdraw</option><option value="Text">Text</option><option value="Note">Note</option>';

Comment: I want to find "Redeem" and remove the option tag completely containing "Redeem" value. Can anyway do it through String indexOf and Substring or any other way can I achieve this?

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: what function you have used for removing redeem by using my regular expression?

Comment: str2 = str2.replace(/<[a-zA-z\s]{1,}>Redeem</[a-zA-z\s]{1,}>/, "");

Comment: use this /<[a-zA-z\s=]{1,}>Redeem</[a-zA-z\s]{1,}>/

Comment: @Sundar: I tried with below code, but not sure where I am making mistake  var str2 = '<option value="Renew">Renew</option><option value="Redeem">Redeem</option><option value="Withdraw">Withdraw</option><option value="Text">Text</option><option value="Note">Note</option>'; str2 = str2.replace( /<[a-zA-z\s=]{1,}>Redeem</[a-zA-z\s]{1,}>/, "");
alert(str2);

Comment: @Sumita Sinha use this str2 = str2.replace( /<[a-zA-z\s=]{1,}>Redeem</[a-zA-z\s]{1,}>/ig, "");

Comment: Tried executing in W3Schools editor, but unfortunately code str2 = str2.replace( /<[a-zA-z\s=]{1,}>Redeem</[a-zA-z\s]{1,}>/ig, "");   gives compilation error.Pls suggest

Comment: @sundar
Tried executing in W3Schools editor, but unfortunately code str2 = str2.replace( /<[a-zA-z\s=]{1,}>Redeem</[a-zA-z\s]{1,}>/ig, ""); gives compilation error.Pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

Could you use

```
maturityDlgPrincipleSelectHtml.replace(/\<option value=\"Redeem\"\>Redeem\<\/option\>/,"");
```

Or is this being too specific.